# Achievements are displayed differently

Tags: bug, design, achievements-dialog

This is what my achievements on all SE sites look like on Firefox 49.0.2 and Chrome 54.0.2840.99 m (64-bit):

[image]

But this is what it looks like on Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0:

[image]

If I recall correctly, the latter picture is how it used to be in all browsers.

---

It seems like the `width` of `.achievements-dialog .message-text` is too big:

```
.achievements-dialog .message-text {
    margin-left: 2px;
    width: 276px;
}
```

---

Is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

Comment: No repro here (yes, the latter is how it should look).

Comment: Looks good in Chrome here too.

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 49.0.2

Comment: [Happened to someone else today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301420/achievements-dropdown-is-disorganised), you remember how it got resolved for you, if at all? @Lukas