# Achievements dropdown is disorganised

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, achievements-dialog

This is the achievements drop-down on Ask Ubuntu:

[image]

It doesn't look very good. The same happens on Meta SE - so it's a new and old top-bar issue.

---

Mac OS 10.12.6, Chrome 60.0.3112.113. Also happens in Safari 11.0 and Chrome incognito mode with no extensions, so is not a user-script issue. Zoom at 100%.

Does not happen with Chrome on Windows 10.

Comment: What browser? What OS? Do you have any extensions/add-ons/plugins/user scripts installed? Are you zoomed in/out?

Comment: No repro. It's probably something on your side, or at least something browser related (can't know since you don't tell what browser/OS you use). First thing to blame is some fancy userscript you installed and forgot about. Try with different browser and see.

Comment: @Oded Edited...

Comment: @Oded FYI same bug was reported before, maybe it can help you (or other dev) to reproduce somehow.

Comment: Might be related to the Mac OS then.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Which would suggest it's not a duplicate.

Comment: No repro in Chrome on Mac (Sierra) here.

Comment: Repro on Chrome 61.0.3163.100 64-bit on Windows 10: https://i.imgur.com/3uVvU5D.png - no userscripts or extensions enabled

Comment: @Oded I've provided a fix for the problem. Could this be looked at?

Answer (score 3):

I've updated our CSS to fix the issue.

This is now deployed cross network.

Answer (score 2):

As per usual, CSS seems to be the culprit. When this happened [last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286813/307833), it seems the `width` property on the text's style was too wide. The offending CSS is this:

```
.achievements-dialog .message-text {
    margin-left: 2px;
    width: 278px;
}
```

Changing the `width` to `80%` (or `260px`) fixes the issue.