# Achievements menu layout is messed up

Tags: bug, design, achievements-dialog

This just started happening sometime in the last day:

[image]

There shouldn't be a white column to the right hand side, and the text should be beside the award, rather than beneath it.

This appears to be a regression of [an issue from October](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301420/achievements-dropdown-is-disorganised). (Thanks Shadow.)

Comment: No repro here (Chrome, Win 7). What browser are you using? Is it the same on all SE sites?

Comment: [Dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301420/achievements-dropdown-is-disorganised), probably wrongly tagged as completed.

Comment: @ale Windows 10, Chrome, userscripts disabled, every site I've been on.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard That was resolved back in October, so might be a regression. It definitely hasn't been like this since October, so it was fixed for a while! I've [left a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301420/#comment991967_301886) on Oded's response pointing him to this post.

Comment: Oded can't do anything about it now, he's no longer working for Stack Exchange. Better delete the comment.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard Nuts, you're right. OK, done.